# R: Perform calculation on integer-character entry

Tags: r, types, average, tidyr

I have a `data frame` with entries (type: `character`) that are either `integers` or a range of `integers` like this, separated by a minus:

```
ds1:
    Values
    12-15
    5-10
    2-3
    12
    40
    3
```

I want to generate a data frame that keeps the integer values but calculates the average of the entries that have a range (type for both: `num`), i.e.:

```
ds2:
    Values
    13.5
    7.5
    2.5
    12
    40
    3
```

So far, I've only managed to remove the minus sign. But this approach gives me the lower bound instead of a method to calculate the average between the two bounds. Am I approaching this wrong? I'd appreciate any help and don't have a package preference.

Comment: You can do: `sapply(strsplit(ds1$Values, "-"), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))`.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you @27ϕ9!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `separate_rows()` function from the tidyr package:

```
values<-c("12-15", "5-10",  "2-3", "12",
          "40",  "3")

df <-data.frame(values)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% separate_rows(values, sep="[^[:alnum:].]+") %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% summarize(values=mean(as.numeric(values)))

     ID values
  <int>  <dbl>
1     1   13.5
2     2    7.5
3     3    2.5
4     4   12  
5     5   40  
6     6    3
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e! I ended up using @27ϕ9's suggestion but appreciate your response.